Not able to connect to gradle.com from intellij
Im using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.2 (Ultimate Edition) & im facin below error suddenly in one of my lcoal workspace while trying to run the application. i have tried checking the setting & the gradle toggle offline is off & also im directly able to connect to below link from browser. Also i cross compared proxy. and none the other team members configured any proxy settings.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/gradle/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin/3.6.1/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin-3.6.1.pom'.

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/gradle/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin/3.6.1/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin-3.6.1.pom'.
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:130)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRawGet(HttpClientHelper.java:92)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performGet(HttpClientHelper.java:96)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:43)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:28)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultExternalResourceConnector.openResource(DefaultExternalResourceConnector.java:56)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.openResource(ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.java:38)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.AccessorBackedExternalResource.withContentIfPresent(AccessorBackedExternalResource.java:130)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$11.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:237)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$11.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:229)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.withContentIfPresent(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:229)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.copyToCache(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:199)
... 204 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to plugins.gradle.org:443 [plugins.gradle.org/104.16.72.101, plugins.gradle.org/104.16.73.101] failed: Connection refused: connect
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:170)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:146)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.executeGetOrHead(HttpClientHelper.java:135)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:105)
... 225 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:368)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
... 237 more
2024-09-02T17:49:14.124+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/gradle/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin/3.6.1/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin-3.6.1.pom
2024-09-02T17:49:14.124+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor] Constructing external resource: https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/gradle/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin/3.6.1/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin-3.6.1.pom
2024-09-02T17:49:14.125+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/gradle/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin/3.6.1/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin-3.6.1.pom' started
2024-09-02T17:49:14.125+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor] Constructing external resource: https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/gradle/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin/3.6.1/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin-3.6.1.pom
2024-09-02T17:49:14.125+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper] Performing HTTP GET: https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/gradle/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin/3.6.1/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin-3.6.1.pom
2024-09-02T17:49:14.125+0530 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies] CookieSpec selected: default
2024-09-02T17:49:14.126+0530 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache] Auth cache not set in the context
2024-09-02T17:49:14.126+0530 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection request: [route: {s}->https://plugins.gradle.org:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 20; total allocated: 0 of 20]
2024-09-02T17:49:14.126+0530 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection leased: [id: 9][route: {s}->https://plugins.gradle.org:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 20; total allocated: 1 of 20]
2024-09-02T17:49:14.126+0530 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Opening connection {s}->https://plugins.gradle.org:443
2024-09-02T17:49:14.126+0530 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] Connecting to plugins.gradle.org/104.16.72.101:443
2024-09-02T17:49:14.127+0530 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Connecting socket to plugins.gradle.org/104.16.72.101:443 with timeout 30000
2024-09-02T17:49:16.185+0530 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] Connect to plugins.gradle.org/104.16.72.101:443 timed out. Connection will be retried using another IP address
2024-09-02T17:49:16.186+0530 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] Connecting to plugins.gradle.org/104.16.73.101:443
2024-09-02T17:49:16.186+0530 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Connecting socket to plugins.gradle.org/104.16.73.101:443 with timeout 30000
2024-09-02T17:49:18.241+0530 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection] http-outgoing-9: Shutdown connection
2024-09-02T17:49:18.241+0530 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Connection discarded
2024-09-02T17:49:18.242+0530 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection released: [id: 9][route: {s}->https://plugins.gradle.org:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 20; total allocated: 0 of 20]
2024-09-02T17:49:18.242+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/gradle/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin/3.6.1/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin-3.6.1.pom'
2024-09-02T17:49:18.242+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/gradle/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin/3.6.1/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin-3.6.1.pom' completed
2024-09-02T17:49:18.248+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.oldresult.TransientConfigurationResultsBuilder] Flushing resolved configuration data in Binary store in C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle2243534232657512061.bin. Wrote root 2.
2024-09-02T17:49:18.251+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Resolve dependencies of detachedConfiguration1'
2024-09-02T17:49:18.251+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Resolve dependencies of detachedConfiguration1' completed
2024-09-02T17:49:18.253+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Apply settings file 'settings.gradle' to settings 'bec''
2024-09-02T17:49:18.253+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Apply settings file 'settings.gradle' to settings 'bec'' completed
2024-09-02T17:49:18.253+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Evaluate settings'
2024-09-02T17:49:18.253+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Evaluate settings' completed
2024-09-02T17:49:18.253+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Load build'
2024-09-02T17:49:18.253+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Load build' completed
2024-09-02T17:49:18.256+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService] Worker lease root.1 completed (0 worker(s) in use)
2024-09-02T17:49:18.256+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker Thread 2: released lock on root.1
2024-09-02T17:49:18.260+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Build finished for file system watching' started
2024-09-02T17:49:18.260+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Build finished for file system watching'
2024-09-02T17:49:18.260+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Build finished for file system watching' completed
2024-09-02T17:49:18.260+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Run build'
2024-09-02T17:49:18.260+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Run build' completed
2024-09-02T17:49:18.301+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for cache directory md-supplier (C:\Users\xxx.gradle\caches\6.9.1\md-supplier)
2024-09-02T17:49:18.301+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on cache directory md-supplier (C:\Users\xxx.gradle\caches\6.9.1\md-supplier).
2024-09-02T17:49:18.302+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for cache directory md-rule (C:\Users\xxx.gradle\caches\6.9.1\md-rule)
2024-09-02T17:49:18.303+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on cache directory md-rule (C:\Users\xxx.gradle\caches\6.9.1\md-rule).
2024-09-02T17:49:18.306+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 0 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.0 secs)
2024-09-02T17:49:18.308+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 0 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.0 secs)
2024-09-02T17:49:18.308+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.ResolutionResultsStoreFactory] Deleted 2 resolution results binary files in 0.004 secs
2024-09-02T17:49:18.310+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.deployment.internal.DefaultDeploymentRegistry] Stopping 0 deployment handles
2024-09-02T17:49:18.310+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.deployment.internal.DefaultDeploymentRegistry] Stopped deployment handles
2024-09-02T17:49:18.311+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for file hash cache (H:\Workspace\bec.gradle\6.9.1\fileHashes)
2024-09-02T17:49:18.311+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on file hash cache (H:\Workspace\bec.gradle\6.9.1\fileHashes).
2024-09-02T17:49:18.258+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
2024-09-02T17:49:18.259+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2024-09-02T17:49:18.259+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
2024-09-02T17:49:18.259+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Where:
2024-09-02T17:49:18.259+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Auto-applied by using --scan
2024-09-02T17:49:18.259+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
2024-09-02T17:49:18.259+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
2024-09-02T17:49:18.259+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Plugin [id: 'com.gradle.enterprise', version: '3.6.1', artifact: 'com.gradle:gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin:3.6.1'] was not found in any of the following sources:
2024-09-02T17:49:18.259+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
2024-09-02T17:49:18.259+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
2024-09-02T17:49:18.259+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] - Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.gradle:gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin:3.6.1')
2024-09-02T17:49:18.259+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   Searched in the following repositories:
2024-09-02T17:49:18.259+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]     Gradle Central Plugin Repository
2024-09-02T17:49:18.259+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
2024-09-02T17:49:18.259+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
2024-09-02T17:49:18.259+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  Run with --scan to get full insights.
2024-09-02T17:49:18.260+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
2024-09-02T17:49:18.260+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
2024-09-02T17:49:18.260+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger]
2024-09-02T17:49:18.260+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 16s
2024-09-02T17:49:18.375+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for checksums cache (H:\Workspace\bec.gradle\checksums)
2024-09-02T17:49:18.375+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on checksums cache (H:\Workspace\bec.gradle\checksums).
2024-09-02T17:49:18.452+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore] VCS Checkout Cache (H:\Workspace\bec.gradle\vcs-1) has last been fully cleaned up 8 hours ago
2024-09-02T17:49:18.452+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache VCS Checkout Cache (H:\Workspace\bec.gradle\vcs-1) was closed 0 times.
2024-09-02T17:49:18.452+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache VCS metadata (H:\Workspace\bec.gradle\6.9.1\vcsMetadata-1) was closed 0 times.
2024-09-02T17:49:18.480+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] The daemon has finished executing the build.
17:49:18: Execution finished 'bootRun --scan --debug'.

Could you share the full log (https://uploads.jetbrains.com/)? Can you also elaborate on the networking setup? Is there actually a proxy / firewall / any other solution that may block or alter network traffic in the way?

Getting error while trying to upload

the connection to that url is successful when tested rom http proxy connection

Both issues (Gradle and upload) suggest there is a networking problem in your environment. Might be a good idea to consult with your Network Team, maybe your machine (or the subnet it is in) got misconfigured somehow. Also, try supplying proxy settings to Gradle directly (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/networking.html) as it does not inherit them from IDEA.
